# Timezone bug when retrieving "time" field?

Tags: getstream-io

The manual [specifies](https://getstream.io/docs/#uniqueness) that uniqueness is based on `foreign_id` and `time` fields.

I have an activity where a user joins a specific event. The event has its own start date which I want to display in the timelines, therefore I am submitting it as extra data (as well as name and location etc, but I omitted those here to prevent clutter).
I submitted the activity with the following activity array to a user feed. Notice I am in Amsterdam, which is (at the moment) in a timezone of GMT+0200:

```
Array
(
    [actor] => User:3
    [verb] => join
    [object] => Event:2
    [event_start] => 2016-09-26T19:00:00+0200
    [to] => Array
        (
            [0] => notification:2
        )

    [foreign_id] => join:2
    [time] => 2016-09-16T13:29:13+0200
)
```

When I retrieve that users' user feed, this comes back as:

```
{  
   "duration":"17ms",
   "next":"",
   "results":[  
      {  
         "actor":"User:3",
         "event_start":"2016-09-26T19:00:00+0200",
         "foreign_id":"join:2",
         "id":"cb0f4a80-7c00-11e6-8080-80010479bedb",
         "object":"Event:2",
         "origin":null,
         "target":null,
         "time":"2016-09-16T11:29:13.000000",
         "to":[  
            "notification:2"
         ],
         "verb":"join"
      }
   ]
}
```

Notice the difference in the date fields. Both were submitted as ISO8601 fields, but only the `event_start` field is returned as such. The `time` field is returned in a different format but without any timezone indicator. It's apparently converted to UTC time but it's lacking [the trailing Z that should indicate that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC). Therefor I cannot reliable use it as a time indicator.

I could work around this by adding another time field to the activity array (which works fine and returns a correct ISO8601 date), but that feels quite redundant.

Is this a bug, am I doing something wrong or should we simply not rely on the `time` field for an indication of when the activity took place?

Answer (score 3):

API v1.0 stores the `time` field in UTC timezone but sadly it does not properly return the trailing `Z`. This will be fixed in later API versions, but not on this one.

You can safely expect the `time` field to be always returned as UTC when you query the APIs.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, Tomasso. I understand you cannot change the functionality of an API in production, so I'll take your word for it then :)

Comment: Thanks @Tomasso - will this ever be fixed?