# Why does Stream remove the time zone code when setting a timestamp?

Tags: getstream-io

I've observed that if you create an activity with a timestamp like this:

```
2010-09-17T14:27:37.860Z
```

It will be stored like this:

```
2010-09-17T14:27:37.860
```

Note the missing time zone code. From what I can tell, this violates the ISO standard, and it definitely produces complications in JavaScript with the Date object. I have always had to map the timestamp back to the correct timestamp by adding a Z character, which is kind of crazy.

Here's some code that hopefully illustrates why this is a problem:

```
const now = new Date('2010-09-17T14:27:37.860Z');
const notNow = new Date('2010-09-17T14:27:37.860');
console.log(now);
// Fri Sep 17 2010 09:27:37 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
console.log(notNow);
// Fri Sep 17 2010 14:27:37 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

What's going on here? Am I misunderstanding something or is this a bug with Stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right; the `activity.time` field is returned without offset information even though they are localized as UTC.

This is something that was introduced early on and that was not possible to fix without breaking a number of existing API clients that rely on this time format.

Stream's API stores `activity.time` as UTC (the offset specified in the user input will be respected). If you use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) you can parse the time string correctly like this

```
moment.tz("2010-09-17T14:27:37.860", "UTC")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you recommend working around this in a JavaScript ecosystem? Should times be massaged before sending them to Stream? Or should the timestamps from Stream be corrected?

Comment: The API will respect activity.time timezone information and will store that as UTC (offset will be applied ofc).

Comment: Thanks. I don't use moment but I'll see what I can figure out. Appreciate the reply!

Comment: May I suggest documenting this more explicitly?

Comment: For others who stumble upon this, the following question is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39531436/timezone-bug-when-retrieving-time-field